# Isolated Points in Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Admit the following set theory result : If X is an infinite set and $\mathbb{Q}$  is the set of rational, then there is a bijection $f: X \longrightarrow X \times \mathbb{Q}$. Conclude from this that one can introduce into every infinite set a metric without isolated points.

Thans in advance.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think the idea is to just use the metric in $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, if you want to find $d(a,b)$ where $a,b \in X$, then look at $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ which have associated rational number $r,s$, and so we define $d(a,b)$ to just be $|r-s|$.

Comment: JonHales. Sorry, but I don't really understand your answer. Can you give more details, please? Thank you.

Comment: @JonHales With this construction you will get distinct points with zero distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(X,d), (Y,e)$ are metric spaces then the metric $f(\,(x,y),\,(x',y')\,)=d(x,x')+e(y,y')$ generates the topology of the product-space $X\times Y$.

If $Y$ has no isolated points then neither does $X\times Y.$ This holds for any spaces $X,Y.$

So let $d$ be "the" discrete metric, i.e. $d(x,x')=1$ if $x\ne x'.$ And let $Y=\Bbb Q$  with $e(y,y')=|y-y'|.$

The metric $f$ on $X\times \Bbb Q$ is equivalent to the metric $d'$ of the Answer from Berci. That is, $f$ and $d'$ generate the same topology.

Answer (score 4):

Define a metric on $X'=X\times\Bbb Q$ by
$$d'((x,r),\,(y,s)):=\left\{\matrix{|r-s|&\text{if }x=y\text{ and }|r-s|<1\\ 1&\text{otherwise}}\right.$$
Verify that this is a metric where no point $(x,r)$ is isolated.

Finally, pull back the metric by the bijection $f:X\to X\times\Bbb Q$, i.e. define $d(x,y):=d'(f(x),\,f(y))$.

Comment: I understood,  Berci. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you verified that $d'$ is indeed a metric?

Comment: @Berci $d'$ is not a metric, eg $x\ne y$, $d'((x,0),(x,3))>d'((x,0),(y,0))+d'((y,0),(x,3))$.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, added condition '$|r-s|<1$`.

Comment: @Berci I'm probably missing something. What if you take $f(x):=(x,0)$, isn't $d(x,y)$ the discrete metric?

Comment: Yes, that's the discrete metric, however $f$ is not bijective.